# Change size of image to display with PySimpleGUI

Tags: python, user-interface, desktop-application, pysimplegui

I'm trying to build a header/navigation bar with an image before the title.

Trying to replicate this mockup
[Image of mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xd91q.png)

The image is displaying like this (only show the center of the image, the headphone)
[How it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ubIR.png)

And I want to display like this
[How it should to looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spJye.png)

here is my code

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

# list columns of the view
header = [
    # show icon and name of the store
    [
        sg.Image(r'./images/lofigirl.png',size=(100,100)),
        sg.Text("App title", size=(10, 1), justification='center', font=("Helvetica", 12)),
        sg.Text("Option 1", size=(10, 1), justification='center', font=("Helvetica", 12)),
        sg.Text("Option 2", size=(10, 1), justification='center', font=("Helvetica", 12)),
    ]
]

content = [
    [
        sg.Text("Content", size=(60, 1), justification='center', font=("Helvetica", 25)),
    ]
]

# create window
window = sg.Window(
    'Window title',
    header + content,
    location=(100, 100)
)

# event loop
while True:
    event, values = window.read(timeout=20)
    
    if event == 'Exit' or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Resize by PIL

```py
from io import BytesIO
from pathlib import Path
from PIL import Image, UnidentifiedImageError
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def resize(image_file, new_size, encode_format='PNG'):
    im = Image.open(image_file)
    new_im = im.resize(new_size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
    with BytesIO() as buffer:
        new_im.save(buffer, format=encode_format)
        data = buffer.getvalue()
    return data

size = (500, 500)

layout = [
    [sg.Input(enable_events=True, readonly=True, expand_x=True, key='-FILENAME-'),
     sg.FileBrowse()],
    [sg.Image(size=size, background_color='green', key='-IMAGE-')],
    [sg.Text(expand_x=True, background_color='gray', key='Status')],
]
window = sg.Window('Title', layout)

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break

    elif event == '-FILENAME-':
        window['Status'].update('')
        image_file = values[event]
        if Path(image_file).is_file():
            try:
                window['-IMAGE-'].update(data=resize(image_file, size))
            except UnidentifiedImageError:
                window['Status'].update('Image file unidentified !')

window.close()
```